# Dealing with a variable containing a path with brackets

Tags: powershell, path, brackets

I struggle with this

```
$test =  "C:\[1]test.mp3"
$FilePath = dir $test
Write-Host "FilePath: " $FilePath
```

The path isn't recognized (the code works if the name doesn't contain the brackets).

I found [this info from MS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/resolve-path), I tried without success:

```
$FilePath = dir $(-LiteralPath $test)
```

The other questions about it talk about complicate issues, I don't find anything about this basic problem.

Comment: Try `$FilePath = dir -LiteralPath $test`

Comment: Nitpicking: As `dir` is an alias for `Get-ChildItem` it returns FileInfoObjects not just a `FilePath` - so the variable naming is at best unlucky. There must be other circumstances with your file, it does work here (tested on `A:\[1]test.mp3`) Did you try on a different folder?

Comment: @VivekKumarSingh sorry, it works now! Please add it as answer, you are the one who found it. (I tried several time, but I probably made a mistake)

Comment: $filePath = Dir 'C:\*.*' -Filter '[1]test.mp3'

Comment: @VivekKumarSingh A single line answer will be perfect (the first part of the answer below is wrong)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`dir` is an alias for `Get-ChildItem`. `LiteralPath` parameter was not working for you since you were not using it in the correct way.

So you have to change your code from `$FilePath = dir $(-LiteralPath $test)` to

`$FilePath = dir -LiteralPath $test`

Just as an additional read, what you were trying to do is called a sub-expression operator. You can read more about it here in the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators?view=powershell-6).

Answer (score 1):

The square bracket is a special character in PowerShell, used for things like regular expressions, so you can't use it directly when specifying the file/directory name.  Instead try escaping them with double back ticks, like so:

```bsh
$test =  'C:\``[1``]test.mp3'
```

That should enable you to run your dir command (alias of `Get-ChildItem`), although you might still have some trouble depending on what you what to do with such named files.

Depending on what you're permitted to do with the files, you might like to replace the square brackets, e.g.

```bsh
$test = 'C:\``[1``]test.mp3'
$testName = (Get-ChildItem $test).Name
$newName = $testName -replace '\[','(' -replace '\]',')'
Move-Item -LiteralPath $testName $test2
```

Some of these things can be a little tricky, but hope that helps.

Comment: it's not the answer, but it definitely helps (so +1 and thanks!)

Answer (score 0):

Use single quotes around your string:

```
$test =  'C:\[1]test.mp3'
```

With single quotes Powershell won't try to perform string substitutions.

**UPDATE 1**

@LotPings thx for the comment.

You've to use the `-LiteralPath` parameter of `Get-ChildItem`, [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-childitem?view=powershell-6):

> -LiteralPath
>
> Specifies a path to one or more locations. The value of LiteralPath is used exactly as it is typed. No characters are interpreted as wildcards. If the path includes escape characters, enclose it in single quotation marks. Single quotation marks tell PowerShell not to interpret any characters as escape sequences.

Example:

```
> Get-ChildItem


    Directory: C:\Temp\soTest

Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                -------------         ------ ----
-a----        22.08.2019    10:05              0 [1] abc.txt

> $test =  '.\[1] abc.txt'
> Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath $test


    Directory: C:\Temp\soTest

Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                -------------         ------ ----
-a----        22.08.2019    10:05              0 [1] abc.txt
```

Comment: Wrong track, the assignment isn't the problem, `gci $test` after your command won't return anything unless there is a file `1test.mp3` ***without*** brackets.

Comment: @Moerwald thanks but it doesn't work (you can try it with 2 files: [1]test.mp3 and test.mp3  , only the second works)